# In retrofit2, Call<String> is working fine in one interface but the same code is not working in other interface

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have found many answers for the error which I am receiving in retrofit but I have some different issue that I am unable to understand.

I have the following code to receive String as response from server in android using retrofit2 library.

***1st case:***

In the following code it is working correctly.

CardService.java

```
package com.go.gocard.card;

import com.go.gocard.model.Card;
import com.go.gocard.model.JsonResponse;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.POST;


public interface CardService {

@POST("savecard")
Call<String> sendCard(@Body Card card);

}
```

This interface is used in some class as:

```
public void sendCard(Card card) {

    Retrofit retrofit = = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(context.getString(CardResources.BASE_URL))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    CardService service = retrofit.create(CardService.class);
    Call<String> resp = service.sendCard(card);
    resp.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            Toast.makeText(context,response.body(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            seeOthers();
            Log.d("Success","Sa");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context,t.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Failure_Reason",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

This works successfully as it prints log **Success: Sa**

***2nd case:***

While I have another interface as:

LoginService.java

```
package com.go.gocard.loginAndRegister;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

/**
* Created by dhruvam on 02/09/2016.
 */
public interface LoginService {

@POST("registration")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<String> register(@Field("email") String emailId, @Field("pass") String pass);
```

}

and when I use this interface in some class in same manner as above then it prints failure log as: **error: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $**
:

```
public void register(View v)
{
    if(validated())
    {
        task = "register";

       Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(context.getResources().getString(R.string.base_url))
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

       LoginService service = retrofit.create(LoginService.class);
       Call<String> resp = service.register(email, pass);
       resp.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                    Log.d("message",response.body());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("error",t.getMessage());
                }
            });

    }
}
```

**Both cases are from same android app.**

Server is simply returning the string in both the cases then why error is raised in only second case while it is working perfectly in first case.
Why the **GsonConverterFactory** is not able to parse the response as String in second case.

Plz help anyone.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Server returns the following data in **1st case:**

```
response.getWriter().print("true");
```

while in **2nd case:**

```
response.getWriter().print("success");
```

Comment: In your 2nd case where is the `@Body` that you are posting to the backend?

Comment: in fact both case not the same. in first case you send it as Body which is work fine in second you send it as FormData which doesn't work.

Comment: backend task is completed successfully in both the cases as the file I am updating on server is updated successfully but the error is due to data returned by server to the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution on [github.com](http://github.com) but they removed this issue because of silly question.

Error is not in retrofit but instead it is in response sent from the server.

I modified the response in **2nd case** as:

```
response.getWriter().print("\"success\""); // making it a json string by including double quotes
```

Only **"success"** is not a **json string** until we include **double quotes**

Retrofit receives the json response and response in 1st case is **"true"** which is treated as Boolean literal in json and hence no error .

But in 2nd case **"success"** is not **properly formatted** according to the json string. So modifying it as above removes the error.